Python Generators and yield
I am sending a request from front end to backend method to trigger, here my back end method is receiving the request; so in Python flask back end method  I am using generator and yield to iterate a list of 100000 elements send one by one to front end, so With one request from front end backend method should send 100k responses to front end, but I am getting this error:

labeling:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://0.0.0:3000/fetch_list' from origin 'http://0.0.0.3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When I send one request from front end generator method should send responses one by one to front end method.
Suppose I have list in backend and iterate it send one each element one by one to front end using yield until the last element of the list. If list contains 10 elements then 10 responses should send to front end with one API request from front  end method.
Here is my front end method:
const fetchNumbers = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const response = awaitaxios.get(`http://0.0.0:3000}/fetch_list`);
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error occurred: ${error}`);
    }
};

Backend flask Python code :
@app.route('/fetch_list')
@cross_origin(origin="*", headers=["Content-Type"])
def generate_numbers():
    # Define a list of numbers
    print("Generate_numbers method is called")
    numbers = [i for i in range(1, 100001)]
    def generate():
        print("generate list")
        for num in numbers:
            yield jsonify({
                'number': num.flatten().tolist()
                })
            print(f"Sent number: {num}")
    return Response(generate(), content_type='application/json')


One HTTP request can only result in one HTTP response. You need a socket to stream multiple messages. A generator won't magically work across HTTP.

Thanks deceze, please can you give a example about how to use the  socket.

you're missing a 0 in your ip address "0.0.0"
also, i believe you're looking for flask socket or sending the list in one response as there is no way to respond multiple times to the same request
also: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid ip address, you should use 127.0.0.1 or whatever host your server is on

Thanks Kenzo Staelens, Actually  I would like to stream pcd files , So I am using react and type script  node js  technologies for front end , and python for backend , so  if  I sent request from front end to backend , pcd files should stream on GUI
